# Fast way to find the row associated with a given Guid across many SQL databases and tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, data-structures, bloom-filter

I have a number of SQL databases, each with plenty of tables. These predominantly have randomly generated Guids as row primary keys. I would like a way to locate the table and row data associated with a given Guid (with no type information).

So I was considering setting up a Bloom filter for each table and cache it somewhere. I would first test the Guid against the filter then subsequently query the database or cache for the data (or for a false positive). However I have never worked with them before and so do not know what their performance characteristics are like, and if they would be an effective solution to my problem.

**Database characteristics:**

- ~100 tables to choose between. Some are far more likely to be chosen than others.
- No rows are ever deleted (unless a manual cleanup after a bug) so I am not concerned about not being able to remove information from a bloom filter.
- More structure than data! Everything fits on one server.

Is this a solution worth investigating? Am I better of sticking to caching more conventional lookup structures? If I go for Bloom, are there any shortcuts to the hashing functions given that Guids are a very independent input?

Comment: Are you saying you'd rather implement Bloom filters in application code than look up foreign key dependencies in the system tables? (Granted there's no guarantee that *every* use of a key, GUID or not, occurs through a foreign key reference, but still.)

Comment: By 'system tables' do you mean that there is database metadata that I can query? I do not know my way around these tables so please enlighten me. There is a good chance that every GUID referenced piece of data I care about appears in a foreign key.

Comment: Every SQL database has at least one way to query metadata. The "standard" way is to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. But, since these are usually views built on top of system tables, some platforms also let you query the underlying tables directly. (Don't know what platform you're using, but you might want to tag your question with it.)

Comment: SQL-Server. Recently enough out of college so I instinctively tend to try to algorithm things away if the best solution isn't under my nose.

Comment: When it comes to SQL databases, keep this in mind no matter what your problem: "You are not the first." You're probably not even the first person with your particular problem today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your platform's help for "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" or "system tables". As far as I know, every SQL dbms has at least one way for you to query metadata. The "standard" way is to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, but their content varies among dbms vendors.

In [PostgreSQL's information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html), this query will show you all the table and column names that have foreign key constraints, and also their target table and column names.

```
select kc2.table_name as fk_table_name, kc2.column_name as fk_column_name, 
       kc1.table_name as ref_table_name, kc1.column_name as ref_column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.referential_constraints rc
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage kc1 
        on rc.constraint_catalog = kc1.constraint_catalog
       and rc.constraint_schema = kc1.constraint_schema
       and rc.unique_constraint_name = kc1.constraint_name
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage kc2 
        on rc.constraint_catalog = kc1.constraint_catalog
       and rc.constraint_schema = kc1.constraint_schema
       and rc.constraint_name = kc2.constraint_name
order by kc2.table_name, kc2.column_name
```

[SQL Server Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a bloom filter? You indicated that your db is light on data, so is the compactness of a bloom filter really necessary?  Since false positives are possible with bloom filters, you'll need to go through the effort to perform an index lookup in one or more tables to confirm a match (so there's no real performance benefit over any other index lookup).  If you're going to maintain a bloom filter during insert operations, you could just as easily maintain a regular index in a common table.

So why not create one or more simple tables to maintain this information? You could have a table with 2 columns (Guid-Value and Table-ID) that also forms the primary key, and use that as your index.